# Why doesn't the rowcount and results show at the same time, when i am using setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well, i am trying to query some data and show the results and also see the row_count. Below is the code i am using:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db_xx";



    try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_registration_requests where FLAG_ACCEPTANCE="0"';

     $q = $conn->query($sql);
     $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


     $rows = $q->fetchAll();
    $num_rows = count($rows);


    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
     die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

And for showing in table::

```
<table id="table_reg_confirm" border="1"  cellpadding="5px" ">
         <thead bgcolor="#999999">
             <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Last Name</th>
             <th>Email</th>
             <th>Phone</th>
             <th>Address</th>
             <th>Date Of Birth</th>
             <th>Comments</th>                               
             </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>

             <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): 
                $i=0;
             ?>
                 <tr>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['ID'])?></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="frname".<?php $i; ?> value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['FIRST_NAME']).$i?> "></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['LAST_NAME']); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['EMAIL']); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['PHONE']); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['ADDRESS']); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['DOB']); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['COMMENTS']); ?></td>
                 </tr>
             <?php  endwhile; ?>

         </tbody>

 </table>
```

To see the row_count::

```
 <?php  echo $num_rows; ?>
```

But whenever i am using `$rows = $q->fetchAll();    $num_rows = count($rows);` for row_count- than the result table isn't showing. WHats wrong with it? except these two lines, result shows fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the while loop line to use foreach:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $r): ?>
...
 <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

You must use the rows that you captured in the $rows array variable. You cannot fetch rows from the pdo handler after already having fetched them once.

Comment: thanks. It actually helped. But the syntax would be: <?php foreach($rows as $r){.......... ..........} ?>

Comment: The formats are interchangeable, some prefer the syntax in the answer when generating html within a loop